# Error installing DVWA in xampp

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

When i try to open localhost/dvwa i get this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\dvwa\dvwa\includes\dvwaPage.inc.php:461 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\dvwa\login.php(8): dvwaDatabaseConnect() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\dvwa\dvwa\includes\dvwaPage.inc.php on line 461
```

and if i go to localhost/dvwa/setup.php i get to the database setup but when i click Create/Reset Database i get this

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\dvwa\dvwa\includes\DBMS\MySQL.php:9 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\dvwa\setup.php(17): include_once() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\dvwa\dvwa\includes\DBMS\MySQL.php on line 9
```

i already change $_DVWA[ 'db_password' ] = ''; and my config.inc.php looks like this

```
<?php

# If you are having problems connecting to the MySQL database and all of the variables below are correct
# try changing the 'db_server' variable from localhost to 127.0.0.1. Fixes a problem due to sockets.
#   Thanks to @digininja for the fix.

# Database management system to use
$DBMS = 'MySQL';
#$DBMS = 'PGSQL'; // Currently disabled

# Database variables
#   WARNING: The database specified under db_database WILL BE ENTIRELY DELETED during setup.
#   Please use a database dedicated to DVWA.
$_DVWA = array();
$_DVWA[ 'db_server' ]   = '127.0.0.1';
$_DVWA[ 'db_database' ] = 'dvwa';
$_DVWA[ 'db_user' ]     = 'root';
$_DVWA[ 'db_password' ] = '';

# Only used with PostgreSQL/PGSQL database selection.
$_DVWA[ 'db_port '] = '5432';

# ReCAPTCHA settings
#   Used for the 'Insecure CAPTCHA' module
#   You'll need to generate your own keys at: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create
$_DVWA[ 'recaptcha_public_key' ]  = '';
$_DVWA[ 'recaptcha_private_key' ] = '';

# Default security level
#   Default value for the secuirty level with each session.
#   The default is 'impossible'. You may wish to set this to either 'low', 'medium', 'high' or impossible'.
$_DVWA[ 'default_security_level' ] = 'impossible';

# Default PHPIDS status
#   PHPIDS status with each session.
#   The default is 'disabled'. You can set this to be either 'enabled' or 'disabled'.
$_DVWA[ 'default_phpids_level' ] = 'disabled';

# Verbose PHPIDS messages
#   Enabling this will show why the WAF blocked the request on the blocked request.
#   The default is 'disabled'. You can set this to be either 'true' or 'false'.
$_DVWA[ 'default_phpids_verbose' ] = 'false';

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the MySQL extension in `php.ini`. Check [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.installation.php).

You have to uncomment line, which contains `extension=php_mysql.dll` (for PHP on Windows) or `extension=mysql.so` (for PHP on Linux) in your `php.ini`. If you're using PHP with a web server, don't forget to restart it after any change in `php.ini`.

It's possible that on Linux you will have to install the extension first:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

Installation should also enable the extension automatically, so you don't have to enable it the `php.ini`. Restart the web server after installation.

Comment: where do i find php.ini?. Im in windows by the way

Comment: Check the output of the [`phpinfo` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php).